# Is double hashing combined with salting an effective password storing technique?

Tags: database, security, passwords

I am trying to store passwords according to the steps below:

1. hashing the password,
2. Adding last four characters of the hashed password to the hashed password again
3. adding salt to result of step 2
4. Hashing the result of step 3

Are there really ways in which hackers can still hack this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there really ways in which hackers can still hack this?

Define hack? Brute force method will always apply for someone gaining access to your system. If someone has a password of 1234, salting and hashing isn't going to make that password stronger. However, if you are worried about reversing a passwords from the hashed value and storing the PW in the clear (which you should be and seems to be the origin of your question), then **yes you are by using a salt and hash.**

> Is double hashing combined with salting an effective password storing
>   technique?

The hash function you are using is important here. First, you need one that is [collision resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance) to ensure two different values don't have a high probability of having the same hash. You didn't state what function you were using (MD5, SHA1, SHA256, etc)

Step 2 here isn't really needed, but certainly adds complexity. This is true for step 4 as well. I would lean towards a more complex has function like SHA2 or SHA3 instead of rehashing to speed things up.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I intend to use SHA-256. Also, I am wondering if a brute Force attack can still hack when I use salt generated dynamically if I intend not to allow users have a weak password such as 1234. I understand it is a bit tough enforcing users to have a complex password

Comment: Password complexity would reduce the brute force attack probability. How you are storing the passwords has nothing to do with this (though you should definitely store them with a salt and has as you are doing). Remember password **length** matters more than **complexity**. [Read here](https://gizmodo.com/the-guy-who-invented-those-annoying-password-rules-now-1797643987) about the guy who invented that idea, and [this comic](https://xkcd.com/936/) that illustrates this. Point is, `thislongbuteasytorememberstringthaticanuseasapassword` is *much* stronger than `*Jh4df4@#$k89u98*(&`

Comment: Nice to know this technique of long meaningful passwords rather than complexity, I can get the users to make use of it

Comment: Start requiring *passphrases* instead of *passwords*. maybe a line from their favorite book, something from their favorite song, etc... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the attacker doesn't know your invention, this is "*security by obscurity*", as soon as the algorithm is known it is nearly as easy to brute-force as a plain salted SHA-*. The problem is, that one can try about [3 Giga SHA-256 hashes per second](http://thepasswordproject.com/oclhashcat_benchmarking) with common hardware and cracker tools even allow some double hashing schemas out of the box.

What you need is a password-hash function like BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2, which have a cost factor to control the necessary time for a single calculation. Additionally you get the comfort to have the salt included in the resulting hash-string, so you do not have to create and store the salt separately.

Comment: I understand. I wouldn't exactly use the logic and steps I specify here. It is good to know various ways to secure password before I implement. Also, it is good to know the password hash functions you specified. Thank you for that information :-)